# Polynomial ring over a PID with infinitely many primes

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

This problem is from a Ph.D Qualifying Exam in algebra.

---

Let $R$ be a PID and $I$ be a nonzero prime ideal of the polynomial ring $R[x]$ such that $R\cap I=0$. Prove that if $R$ has infinitely many prime elements, then $I$ is not maximal.

---

My solution: I just figured out that $I=(f)$ for some irreducible and primitive $f\in R[x]$. Since $R\cap I=0$, one can find a prime element $p \in R$ such that $p \notin I$. Then $J=\langle p,f \rangle$ is an ideal properly containing $I$, and by infinitude of primes, there is another prime $p'\in R\backslash J$. Therefore, $I$ is not maximal.

Is my solution correct?

What I'm worried is that even if $R$ has only finitely many primes, my solution seems to make sense.(i.e. the infinitude of primes of $R$ is too strong.) Is there any solution to this problem fully exploiting the infinitude of primes?

Any comments or corrections are welcome!

Comment: $f$ is not irreducible in general because $R\I $ would be a field and so $I$ would be maximal.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Why does $R/I$ become a field? Here $R$ is PID but $R[x]$ may not be PID, so the nonzero prime ideal and maximal ideal may not be identical.

Comment: Also, if $f$ is not irreducible, then it makes a contradiction to the assumption that $I$ is prime.

Comment: Oooooops, sorry